# Is blog.serverfault.com still active?

Tags: discussion, blog

The last post is one month old, and there are only 2 blog entries (the first one made 1 day before the second). Is it still alive?

Will we see a higher posting frequency in the future (about the same as stack overflow's)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes! It is active. It is in a state of flux at the moment but we should have some exciting new announcements soon.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it was a good idea, unless the goal was to isolate ServerFault from the rest of "the network."

I don't see why a blog post every now and then about the details of servers or switches or storage would be so terrible.  Would it alienate the programmers from SO or the PC specialists from SU?  And from the other point of view, why would you want to alienate the sysadmins on SF by cutting them off from the posts about Area 51, StackApps, etc.?

Comment: I agree. The separation between the two blogs seems pointless to me

Comment: Unless each site gets one ;-) I'm sure they could find enough users willing to send in some blog posts for each separate site focused on that area. Then the separation does make sense